# Combining/Linking reservations/bookings of flight tickets of two people for the common part of the journey

Tags: air-travel, tickets, airlines, bookings, lufthansa

My partner and I will be flying **[to and from]** Frankfurt to our separate home towns in India via Delhi through possibly different online agents.

The itinerary would look like this:

```
 1. FRA --(Lufthansa)--> DEL --Jet Airways--> Destination1 (+ Return) 
[Online Agent XX]
```

```
 2. FRA --(Lufthansa)--> DEL --Air India  --> Destination2 (+ Return)
[Online Agent YY]
```

**Is there a way that we can combine or link the reservations for our common legs in our journeys?, i.e.**,

```
 a. FRA --(Lufthansa)--> DEL
```

```
 b. FRA <--(Lufthansa)-- DEL
```

So that, in case of cancellation, delays, seat changes, upgrades, it affects us together.

I heard that speaking to the airlines (Lufthansa in this case) after booking helps, but would it also work for different destinations?

Comment: What are you intending to gain from linking the reservations?  Being seated together?

Comment: Not only being seated together, also, if one gets an upgrade, for example, or transfer via munich then the other one shouldn't be left out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible to "officially" link two separate tickets (PNRs).  You can request that they annotate one or both records with a comment regarding the other one, in which case any humans processing your tickets may (or may not) see the note and act accordingly, but any automation won't see or understand this.

For sitting together, your best bet would be to check-in online simultaneously and try to get adjacent seats.  This may be difficult on the return leg though, as I would be surprised if Jet will let you select seats on Lufthansa - they're not even in the same alliance.

Comment: Guess thats what i eventually have to do. Thanks jpatokal.